# sending a udp packet from host works but not from container

Tags: docker, udp, containers, statsd, datadog

If I run this command on the host(ubuntu)

```
echo "PD.file.processing:1|c" | nc -w 1 -u localhost 8125
```

It sends the udp packet fine and the dogstatsd agent running on port 8125 picks it up and I can see it.
But when I run the following command  on the docker container on the same host
Here are the port mappings of the container when I do a docker ps

```
8125/udp, 0.0.0.0:20019->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:20018->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:20017->11400/tcp, 0.0.0.0:20016->11401/tcp, 0.0.0.0:20015->11402/tcp

echo "MD.file.returned.success:1|c" | nc -w 1 -u 172.17.0.1 8125
```

This doesn't hit the host and it is not captured by the dogstatsagent running on the host on 8125
Here is the expose line of code in Dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 8125/udp
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`EXPOSE` doesn't publish container ports to the host; it's used more for documenting intent and is considered good practice. You'd usually then need to publish the ports too (e.g. `--publish=8125:8125`).

However, you want to achieve the inverse -- IIUC -- and make the host's port accessible to the container. One way that you may do this is to run the container with `--net=host`. Your container can then access the host's `8125` port.

And, if you did want to access any of the container's ports, you'd be able to do so *without* using publish.